# Not able to dynamically assign values to array

Tags: hardhat, events, testing, arrays, event-handling

I am testing the correct emission of `NFTMintedAll` event on the following function, using `hardhat`:

```
    event NFTMintedAll(
        uint256 requestId,
        address indexed owner,
        uint256[] randomWords,
        uint256 amount,
        address[] indexed variants,
        uint256[] indexed tokenIds
    );

    function requestNFTs(
        address _variant,
        uint256 _variantType,
        uint256 _amount,
        address _paymentToken
    ) external {

        uint256[] memory noRandomWords = new uint256[](0);
        uint256[] memory allTokenIds = new uint256[](_amount);
        address[] memory allVariants = new address[](_amount);

        for (uint256 index = 0; index < _amount; index++) {
            allVariants[index] = address(_variant);
            GMG_ERC721_BaseInterface variant = GMG_ERC721_BaseInterface(_variant);
            require(variant.getRandom() == false, "Variant only available as random mint");
            require(getVariantRemainingSupply(address(variant)) >= 1);
            uint256 tokenCost = variant.getTokenCost(_paymentToken);
            require(tokenCost > 0, "Token cost not set");
            address checkoutWallet = variant.getCheckoutWallet();
            require(checkoutWallet != address(0), "Checkout wallet not set");
            IERC20 token = IERC20(_paymentToken);
            SafeERC20.safeTransferFrom(
                token,
                msg.sender,
                checkoutWallet,
                tokenCost
            );
            uint256 mintedId = variant.mintType(msg.sender, _variantType);
            allTokenIds[index] = mintedId;
        }

        emit NFTMintedAll(0, msg.sender, noRandomWords, _amount, allVariants, allTokenIds);

    }
```

The problem I am having is that the following code is not failing...

```
                await expect(hardhatMintManager.requestNFTs(
                    hardhatCar.address,
                    3,
                    5,
                    hardhatERC20.address
                )).to.emit(hardhatMintManager, "NFTMintedAll").withArgs(
                    0,
                    owner.address,
                    [],
                    5,
                    [],
                    []
                );
```

...meaning that `allVariants` and `allTokenIds` arrays are always empty.

What is the correct way to assign values to a dynamic array in memory?